# An Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

Tags: google-sheets

```
=SORT(UNIQUE({QUERY(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,12)=max(index(z,,12))))(IMPORTRANGE("1madkVso_zaoU9MH2gvtVlTaT2iJ9nMcCxS8ux0Vpz14", "Overview!A2:Z")),"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col13");

QUERY(LAMBDA(z,filter(z,index(z,,17)=max(index(z,,17))))(IMPORTRANGE("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE", "Overview!A2:Z")),"SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col18")}),1,0,3,0,2,1)
```

The formula above was working fine last week but now suddenly gives the error:

> In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more
> rows.

From my understanding, this generally happens when the number of columns are not equal in the data you are appending - but in my case (see formula) the number is equal as there are 5 columns in each (as I mentioned it was indeed working previously). If I remove all but Col1 from both QUERY() formulae then it works again (but of course only shows Col1). Col1 in Query 1 is equal in header to Col1 in Query 2 etc (Col13 in Query 1 has the same header as Col18 in Query 2).

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Just try both the `importrange` formulas separately to troubleshoot and see if its all good

Comment: They indeed do work separately but the issue is that the columns in both files are not exactly equal in structure - hence why I need to use QUERY() to "map" them (e.g. Col13 to Col18). So the issue here is with the QUERY() I believe..

Comment: When I tested your second importrange, it throws an error `result too large`

Comment: If I do:

`={IMPORTRANGE("1madkVso_zaoU9MH2gvtVlTaT2iJ9nMcCxS8ux0Vpz14", "Overview!A2:R");

IMPORTRANGE("1l_xGjh4YNCANLg-npQWzlXXpQJ3nidC4RzBvR62efuE", "Overview!A2:R")}`

I get the same array literal error above. I specified A2:R here because in the second file being imported, we have data up to column R. A2:H works (as tried earlier) however..

Comment: When trying the second IMPORTRANGE I get the ``` Result too large ``` error too, this can cause the "Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows" error could you share a copy / sample of your sheet where the IMPORTRANGE formulas worked separately?

Comment: Here is the spreadsheet with the formulae working (second sheet):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1omejRGkVXY5_9ewNYKeKh9cyqoXAGTJYg7M9BRr5VVA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: this formula in the shared sheet is working with limited data `A:H`. the second importrange throws an error when you include the whole range of `A:R`. when you are trying to stack two importrange arrays and one of them results in error, thats when you see this specific error code: `Array Literal was missing values`. Your solution is to fix the source sheet which has the excessive data the importrange is failing to pull

Comment: That makes sense. The second `importrange` is pulling data from a sheet that has 140,000 rows (blank after 18,000 rows) which now explains the error. I have updated the second `importrange` to `A2:R18500` (as the data is currently reaching the 18,000th row) but this revision also gives the same error. What is the maximum number of cells `importrange` can take? Is there an alternative I can use here to achieve the same purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to importrange ~20 tabs from different sheets - the solve was to try each importrange and I had to 'Allow Access' for each one.

The error always showed as 'In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.' and did not prompt to 'Allow Access'